# bash: /home/user/.bash_completion/alacritty: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

whenever I open the terminal this line

```
bash: /home/user/.bash_completion/alacritty: No such file or directory
```

is displayed. I tried to install `alacritty` terminal but it failed and there after I am seeing this line in the terminal. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear, could you please do add more details ion your question and let us know then.

Comment: Delete the line from your .bashrc or .profile that refers to this path.

Comment: I tried installing alacritty( a GPU-accelerated terminal emulator) from this [link](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) but I was unable to install it due to some dependency issue.There after I am getting this line whenever I open ubuntu terminal

Comment: @Barmar I can't find that path either in .bashrc or .profile

Comment: @SunilKumar Put the details in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [install instructions here](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md#bash), you would have done:

```
echo "source ~/.bash_completion/alacritty" >> ~/.bashrc
```

So, just edit `~/.bashrc` and delete the line `source ~/.bash_completion/alacritty`.

Comment: Edited  ~/.bashrc , issue solved